# Determine the probability mass function, given fifty modems, one thousand customers and an independent p of 0.01

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is Problem 2.4 from Tsitsiklis, Bertsekas, Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition.

[image: problem]

[image: solutiona]

[image: solutionb]

My understanding is that  represents disjoint outcomes.  is the probability that X takes on the value 3.

Why do they say that  is the probability that X takes on a value in the range {50,...,1000}?

Smaller question - should k be equal to {0,1,...,49,50} in the part (a) solution?

Comment: The ISP has only $50$ modems.  When 50 or more customers want a connection, all $50$ modems will be in use.

Comment: right, I didn't notice they started their count from zero. thanks @saulspatz